# For a class with parameterized constructor, create an object without passing arguments

Tags: c++, c++14

I know that we can't do what the title says. But why does the below code work just fine & print `Value of G in class RT: 2` even though object of class RT is created without passing arguments in the line `RT initial_rt;`

```
#include <iostream>
class RT {
    public:
        RT(int var1): G(var1) {std::cout << "Value of G in class RT: "<< G << std::endl;}
    private:
        int G; 
};

class class2 {
    public:
        RT initial_rt;
        class2(RT G) : initial_rt(G) {}
};

int main()
{
    int G=2;
    class2 *cls2_obj = new class2(G);
    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: `RT initial_rt;` just declares the member, initialization is done in constructor.

Comment: @Jarod42 
1) Isn't it the case that a constructor is called when an object is created? & aren't I creating an object in `RT initial_rt;`?

Comment: @Jarod42

2) Also, if it is just initialization of a class member, why doesn't changing the code to `class2(int G) {initial_rt(G);}` work?

Thanks!

Comment: `RT initial_rt;` doesn't create object, you create the whole object with `/*new*/ class2(G);`.

Comment: `{initial_rt(G);}` is not the syntax to initialization, it would call (non-present) `operator()` (as for functor like lambda or std::function).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the replies!
How'd I initialize `initial_rt` from the body of class2's constructor?
Thanks!

Comment: @Jarod42 For class RT, if I remove the parameterized constructor & introduce a default constructor, it gets invoked from the line `RT initial_rt;`. Doesn't this mean that an object of class RT is created at `RT initial_rt;` (Assuming "a constructor is called when an object is created" is true)? 
I'm sorry. I'm confused.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
RT initial_rt;
```

is just a **declaration**.

This line:

```
class2(RT G) : initial_rt(G) {}
```

is the ctor and its **implementation**.

The part after the colon is called **initialization list**, and this is where the `initial_rt` member is being initialized.